# How to mutate_at multiple columns on a condition on each value?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of over 1 million rows, and a column for each hour in the day. I want to mutate each value in those columns, but that modifition depends of the sign of the value.
How can I efficiently do that ?

I could do a gather on those hourly values (then spread), but gather seems to be pretty slow on big dataframes.
I could also just do the same mutate on all 24 columns, but it does not seems like a great solution when mutate_at looks to be able to do exactly that.

I'll probably have to do that kind of mutate again in the near future, and I hope to find something better than a repetitive, boring to read, code.

```
df = data.table(
    "ID" = c(1,1,1,2,2), #Should not be useful there
    "Date" = c(1,2,3,1,2), #Should not be useful there
    "total_neg" = c(1,1,0,0,2),
    "total_pos" = c(4,5,2,4,5),
    "H1" = c(5,4,0,5,-5),
    "H2" = c(5,-10,5,5,-5),
    "H3" = c(-10,6,5,0,10)
)
```

I want to apply something like

```
df%>%
  mutate_at(c("H1", "H2", "H3"), FUN(ifelse( Hour < 0, Hour*total_neg/10, Hour*total_pos/10)))
```

With Hour being the value in each column. And it obviously doesn't work, as written, nor does "." but I'm searching for something that would mean "any value in the columns we select in our mutate_at"

If it helps, I'm currently denormalizing some values with the sum of each actual positives values and negatives values stored in two columns.

In my example, this would be the expected result :

```
df = data.table(
    "ID" = c(1,1,1,2,2),
    "Date" = c(1,2,3,1,2),
    "total_neg" = c(1,1,0,0,2),
    "total_pos" = c(4,5,2,4,5),
    "H1" = c(2,2,0,2,-1),
    "H2" = c(2,-1,1,2,-1),
    "H3" = c(-1,3,1,0,5)
)
df
```

Thanks in advance for any help you may provide, and I must apologize for my mistakes, but as a non-native, I assure you that I do my best !

Comment: It should be `list(~` instead of `FUN`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `FUN` is not an argument in `mutate_at`.  In the new version, the earlier used `fun` is deprecated with `list(~` or simply `~`.  Also, wrap the columns to select in `vars`.  It can also be unquoted or use `vars(starts_with("H"))` or `vars(matches("^H\\d+$"))`.  Also, replace the 'Hour' with `.`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(c("H1", "H2", "H3")), ~ifelse( . < 0, 
           .*total_neg/10, .*total_pos/10))
#. ID Date total_neg total_pos H1 H2 H3
#1  1    1         1         4  2  2 -1
#2  1    2         1         5  2 -1  3
#3  1    3         0         2  0  1  1
#4  2    1         0         4  2  2  0
#5  2    2         2         5 -1 -1  5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works ! I'll accept your answer ASAP.
Thanks again for this suggestion to use "starts_with", it will make the code way better to read !

I basically wrote my first line of R one month ago, and it's pretty hard to get used to how it's written and what means what in all of this.

Can you explain what does FUN and list means there ? And why is list better now ?

Comment: @FBiggio. Regarding your question, it is a tidyverse environment to pass anonymous function.  You could simply do `function(x) x` which does similar to `~`, Why `fun` got deprecated should be in some of the github issues pages for `dplyr`.  I have a feeling that they want to generalize a function, but not sure though