# mutate_at (or across) and ifelse statement

Tags: r, dplyr

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329163/how-to-mutate-at-multiple-columns-on-a-condition-on-each-value), given `tmpp`:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
tmpp <- data.table(
  "ID" = c(1,1,1,2,2), 
  "Date" = c(1,2,3,1,2), 
  "total_neg" = c(1,1,0,0,2),
  "total_pos" = c(4,5,2,4,5),
  "H1" = c(5,4,0,5,-5),
  "H2" = c(5,-10,5,5,-5),
  "H3" = c(-10,6,5,0,10)
)
tmpp
#    ID Date total_neg total_pos H1  H2  H3
# 1:  1    1         1         4  5   5 -10
# 2:  1    2         1         5  4 -10   6
# 3:  1    3         0         2  0   5   5
# 4:  2    1         0         4  5   5   0
# 5:  2    2         2         5 -5  -5  10
```

I want to replace all variables starting with `H`, with `NA` where `total_neg == 1` :

```
#    ID Date total_neg total_pos H1  H2  H3
# 1:  1    1         1         4  NA NA NA
# 2:  1    2         1         5  NA NA NA
# 3:  1    3         0         2  0   5   5
# 4:  2    1         0         4  5   5   0
# 5:  2    2         2         5 -5  -5  10
```

Why don't these work?

```
tmpp %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("H")), ~ifelse( .$total_neg == 1, NA, .))

tmpp %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("H"),
            .funs = list(~ ifelse(.$total_neg == 1, NA, .))))
#im guessing the first dot in the ifelse statements above is referring to the H columns so I tried:
tmpp %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("H"),
                 .funs = list(~ ifelse(tmpp$total_neg == 1, NA, .))))
```

Happy to see `across` version too, thanks

Comment: For your first option, just remove the `.$`...so it will be `mutate_at(vars(matches("H")), ~ ifelse(total_neg == 1, NA, .))`. But since you are defining a `data.table`, why not use `data.table` methods throughout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is correct: inside the purrr-style anonymous function (after your `~`), `.` refers to the function argument, which is a **single column**, not the data frame you piped in. The solution is to simplify by removing the `.$`.

```
tmpp %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("H")), ~ifelse(total_neg == 1, NA, .))
#    ID Date total_neg total_pos H1 H2 H3
# 1:  1    1         1         4 NA NA NA
# 2:  1    2         1         5 NA NA NA
# 3:  1    3         0         2  0  5  5
# 4:  2    1         0         4  5  5  0
# 5:  2    2         2         5 -5 -5 10
```

If you want to modify *"all variables starting with H"*, I'd strongly suggest using `starts_with("H")` rather than `matches("H")`.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to use `$` in `dplyr` pipe. In `mutate_at`/`across` it refers to column value. Try :

```
library(dplyr)
tmpp %>% mutate(across(starts_with('H'), ~replace(., total_neg == 1, NA)))

#   ID Date total_neg total_pos H1 H2 H3
#1:  1    1         1         4 NA NA NA
#2:  1    2         1         5 NA NA NA
#3:  1    3         0         2  0  5  5
#4:  2    1         0         4  5  5  0
#5:  2    2         2         5 -5 -5 10
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple data.table solution that updates all the columns *at once* & *in-place* only for the subset

```
tmpp[total_neg == 1, grep("^H", names(tmpp)) := NA]
tmpp
#    ID Date total_neg total_pos H1 H2 H3
# 1:  1    1         1         4 NA NA NA
# 2:  1    2         1         5 NA NA NA
# 3:  1    3         0         2  0  5  5
# 4:  2    1         0         4  5  5  0
# 5:  2    2         2         5 -5 -5 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `starts_with()` inside `across()`. Here the code:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
tmpp <- data.table(
  "ID" = c(1,1,1,2,2), 
  "Date" = c(1,2,3,1,2), 
  "total_neg" = c(1,1,0,0,2),
  "total_pos" = c(4,5,2,4,5),
  "H1" = c(5,4,0,5,-5),
  "H2" = c(5,-10,5,5,-5),
  "H3" = c(-10,6,5,0,10)
)
#Code
tmpp %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('H'),~ifelse(total_neg==1,NA,.)))
```

Output:

```
   ID Date total_neg total_pos H1 H2 H3
1:  1    1         1         4 NA NA NA
2:  1    2         1         5 NA NA NA
3:  1    3         0         2  0  5  5
4:  2    1         0         4  5  5  0
5:  2    2         2         5 -5 -5 10
```