# How to recode multiple choice answers in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataset with answers to a large number of multiple choice questions. I now want to recode these answers in either true (1) or false (0). I

```
`#ID  q1 q2 q3 cq1 cq2 cq3
 #1   1  2  1  NA  NA  NA
 #2   1  2  2  NA  NA  NA
 #3   2  2  2  NA  NA  NA
 #4   1  2  1  NA  NA  NA`
```

what I want is this:

```
`#ID  q1 q2 q3 cq1 cq2 cq3
 #1   1  2  1  0  0  0
 #2   1  2  2  0  0  1
 #3   2  2  2  1  0  1
 #4   1  2  1  0  0  0`
```

I know that I could write out all answers like this:

```
`data_re <- data %>% 
  mutate(cq1 = if_else(q1==2, 1, 0),
         cq2 = if_else(q2==1, 1, 0),
         cq3 = if_else(q3==2, 1, 0))`
```

But is there any way how to automatically do this (similar to this approach: [How to mutate_at multiple columns on a condition on each value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329163/how-to-mutate-at-multiple-columns-on-a-condition-on-each-value)

However, I would have to generate the variablename of the conditional variable automatically. I tried this:

```
`names_answer_two_correct <- c("q1", "q3")
 cnames_answer_two_correct <- paste0("c", names_answer_two_correct)

 for (i in 1:length(names_answer_two_correct)) {
   data_re <- data %>%
   mutate(names_answer_two_correct[i] = if_else(cnames_answer_two_correct[i]== 2, 1, 0))
}`
```

But I get "Error: unexpected '=' in:"
Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `across` to apply the function to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)
names_answer_two_correct <- c("q1", "q3")

data %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(names_answer_two_correct), 
                ~as.integer(.==2), .names = 'c{col}'), 
         cq2 = as.integer(q2==1)) -> data_re

data_re

#  ID q1 q2 q3 cq1 cq2 cq3
#1  1  1  2  1   0   0   0
#2  2  1  2  2   0   0   1
#3  3  2  2  2   1   0   1
#4  4  1  2  1   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this great solution. Works perfectly!